# return image to angular component from response

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I'm so close I can taste it. My server is returning the image and sending it in the response. 
Now how do I get my angular component to display it. Here's what I have so far.

Here is my service :

```js
getImage(query){
       return this._http.get(this.API_URL + this.baseUrl + query)
         .map(res => res.json());
   }
```

Here is the backend call.

```js
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'});
var image  = new Buffer(rs.recordset[0].Image);
res.end(image);
```

And here is the component :

```js
searchImages(query: string){
    this.searching = true;
    return this._imageService.getImage(query).subscribe( 
       data => {
            this.images = data;
       },
    )
  }
```

The error is :

```
ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0
```

Comment: If what you're getting back is an image, why are you trying to treat it as JSON? Why don't you just set the `src` on an actual `img` element?

Answer (score 0):

In your template, add an img tag:

```
 <img class="myimageclass" [src]="imageInBase64"/>
```

So now you've bound the src to the "imageInBase64" variable of your component.

Since you already have the image as a buffer, just convert it to base 64:

```
this.imageInBase64 = image.toString('base64');
```

The binding + angular change detection should take care of the rest.
Oh and don't forget to manage the width, height etc via inline/css/etc.

Comment: I guess the trouble I have is parsing the response into something my component can display. I have my service returning res.blob. When I call the service, the return object is always blank. I must be missing something.

Comment: Your question states that you are getting the image returned and you are having problem rendering the image. Now you seem to be saying that your backend is not sending your image. You aren't sharing how your backend works so it's hard to tell, but if you are vending the image as a binary payload, you need to use res.arrayBuffer(). If you are saying that is blank, then you aren't sending it correctly and your problem is not with the front end but with the back end.

Comment: I am getting the image returned and I cannot render the image in my <img src> element. I am sending the image as a binary payload, so I will play with res.arrayBuffer() a bit more. Thanks for your suggestions.